# Deployment modes in Glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish

I have a glassfish application that I'd like to have several deployment modes for. IE: Development, production, demo1, etc. How can I specify these configurations?

Thanks.

Comment: What does these "deployment modes" imply?

Comment: Most people have separate development, test, and production workstations, each running a copy of Glassfish configured for that environment.

Comment: Let me clarify: I have some features in my app that I'd like to enable or disable depending on what "mode" the app is deployed in. Is there some way I can set some property via command line when I deploy that I can check inside my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure some JVM Options inside Glassfish and then retrieve them inside your application.

Example:

In Glassfish JVM Options:

**-Dapp.env=production**

In your application:

```
System.getProperty("app.env");
```